# Can't grep output of apt-get

Tags: grep, buffer

If I run:

```
apt-get install --dry-run 2klic-embedded-gui=*-master
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2klic-embedded-gui is already the newest version.
Selected version '3.1.0-8-master' (all 2klic-updates:2klic-updates [all]) for '2klic-embedded-gui'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 182 not upgraded.
```

I'm trying:

```
apt-get install --dry-run 2klic-embedded-gui=*-master 2>&1 | grep gui
```

Which doesn't return anything. So I try `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL apt-get install --dry-run 2klic-embedded-gui=*-master 2>&1 | grep gui
```

This returns line 4 but I'm expecting both line 4 and 5.

Why doesn't line 5 get redirected to `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `apt-get`’s output isn’t a terminal, it defaults to quiet mode, which amongst other things disables outputting the “Selected version” lines. To override this, add `-q=0`:

```
apt-get install -q=0 --dry-run 2klic-embedded-gui=*-master 2>&1 | grep gui
```